# APIB - Always responding to a POST request, regardless of the request payload.

Tags: mocking, api-design, apiblueprint

I'm trying to mock an API with the combination of Api Blueprint and [Drakov](https://github.com/Aconex/drakov). However, for one particular endpoint, I don't know beforehand what the request payload will be. See the below code.

```
# Group Stuff

Description about stuff.

## Main Stuff Resource [stuff/{userId}/response/{responseId}]

+ Parameters
    + userId: specialUser (string, required) - ID of user
    + responseId: 0f9d78ee-005056ad6f10 (string, required) - ID for a particular response.

### Submit Survey Form [POST]

+ Attributes
    + attribute1 (array[object]) - Description for attribute 1
    + attribute2 (array[object]) - Description for attribute 1

+ Request (application/json)
    {attribute1:[],attribute2[]}

+ Response 201  (text/plain; charset=utf8)
    + Headers
        X-XSS-Protection: 0
        Vary:Origin,Accept-Encoding
        Access-Control-Allow-Credentials:true
    + Body
        http://fakeurl.com
```

The above code works, but only when the request payload is *exactly* `{attribute1:[],attribute2:[]}`. Even different whitespacing seems to tip it up, returning a `404` to the user and an error log from Drakov: `[WARNING] JSON body could not be parsed. Using body as is.`

I've tried removing the `Attributes` section , removing the `Request` section, removing the JSON example from the `Request` section, removing everything except for the `Response` section, as well as using the `Schema` section. None of these seems to work, and I can't find any mention of this in the API Blueprint docs.

**How can I always return that response to a POST request at that endpoint, given that I don't know what the format of the request payload or the contents of `attribute1` and `attribute2` will be?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hey @LanceLafontaine I am one of the Drakov maintainers.

Have you tried changing the request to be `{ "attribute1": [], "attribute2": [] }` (In the Blueprint API spec file)

Feel free to post an issue as well on the Drakov repo http://github.com/Aconex/drakov/issues

It's been a short while since I've looked at the parsing code, but I don't think the `Attribute` section is being parsed by Drakov, it will try to match on the `Request` section based on what your've posted.

Comment: This seems to work. It seems to be the combination of using the Requests section as well as the quotes around the attributes that result in it working. +1